# Cannot run program - “Your-first-Kaa-application” using Kaa tutorial on Windows 10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, kaa

Link to the Tutorial: 
http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/

I am on the step "Launch Application". I am using the C++ SDK.

I am trying to create the program in the tutorial, but I am unable to run the program. The instructions are for Linux and require for me to run some commands. Since I cannot do that I figured if I opened it in Visual Studio it would work.

When I opened Visual Studio I found that the "Start" Button was replaced by an "Attach..." Button. I have never seen this before.

Can someone please help me figure out how to run the program?

Thanks.

Code:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <kaa/Kaa.hpp>
#include <kaa/IKaaClient.hpp>
#include <kaa/configuration/manager/IConfigurationReceiver.hpp>
#include <kaa/configuration/storage/FileConfigurationStorage.hpp>
#include <kaa/log/strategies/RecordCountLogUploadStrategy.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

class ConfigurationCollection : public kaa::IConfigurationReceiver {
public:
    ConfigurationCollection()
        : kaaClient_(kaa::Kaa::newClient())
        , samplePeriod_(0)
        , interval_(samplePeriod_)
        , timer_(service_, interval_) 
    {
        // Set a custom strategy for uploading logs.
        kaaClient_->setLogUploadStrategy(
            std::make_shared<kaa::RecordCountLogUploadStrategy>(1, kaaClient_->getKaaClientContext()));
        // Set up a configuration subsystem.
        kaa::IConfigurationStoragePtr storage(
            std::make_shared<kaa::FileConfigurationStorage>(std::string(savedConfig_)));
        kaaClient_->setConfigurationStorage(storage);
        kaaClient_->addConfigurationListener(*this);
        auto handlerUpdate = [this](const boost::system::error_code& err) 
        {
            this->update();
        };
        timer_.async_wait(handlerUpdate);
    }

    ~ConfigurationCollection() 
    {
        // Stop the Kaa endpoint.
        kaaClient_->stop();
        std::cout << "Simple client demo stopped" << std::endl;
    }

    void run() 
    {
        // Run the Kaa endpoint.
        kaaClient_->start();
        // Read default sample period
        samplePeriod_ = kaaClient_->getConfiguration().samplePeriod;
        std::cout << "Default sample period: " << samplePeriod_<< std::endl;
        // Default sample period
        timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(samplePeriod_));
        service_.run();
    }

private:
    static constexpr auto savedConfig_ = "saved_config.cfg";
    std::shared_ptr<kaa::IKaaClient> kaaClient_;
    int32_t samplePeriod_;
    boost::asio::io_service service_;
    boost::posix_time::seconds interval_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;

    int32_t getTemperature() 
    {
        // For sake of example random data is used
        return rand() % 10 + 25;
    }

    void update() 
    {
        kaa::KaaUserLogRecord logRecord;
        logRecord.temperature = getTemperature();
        // Send value of temperature
        kaaClient_->addLogRecord(logRecord);
        // Show log
        std::cout << "Sampled temperature: " << logRecord.temperature << std::endl;
        // Set a new  period of the send data
        timer_.expires_at(timer_.expires_at() + boost::posix_time::seconds(samplePeriod_));
        // Posts the timer event
        auto handlerUpdate = [this](const boost::system::error_code& err) 
        {
            this->update();
        };
        timer_.async_wait(handlerUpdate);
    }

    void updateConfiguration(const kaa::KaaRootConfiguration &configuration) 
    {
        std::cout << "Received configuration data. New sample period: "
            << configuration.samplePeriod << " seconds" << std::endl;
        samplePeriod_ = configuration.samplePeriod;
    }

    void onConfigurationUpdated(const kaa::KaaRootConfiguration &configuration) 
    {
        updateConfiguration(configuration);
    }
};
int main() 
{
    ConfigurationCollection configurationCollection;

    try {
        // It does control of the transmit and receive data
        configurationCollection.run();
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Exception: " << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you start getting swirly-eye syndrome while using kaa, walk away and take some time off until it stops. Trust in me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows page http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/C++/SDK-Windows/ explains the compilation process of C++ SDK and applications for the Windows platform.